# Shorten function to avoid if statements

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

How can I shorten this function, so I don't need any of these `if`?

```
function showhide(element) {
    $('body').on('click', '#'+element, function() {
        if(element == 'export') {
            $('.chat-export').toggle();
            $('.chat-settings').hide();
            $('.chat-users').hide();

        } else if(element == 'settings') {
            $('.chat-export').hide();
            $('.chat-settings').toggle();
            $('.chat-users').hide();

        } else if(element == 'users') {
            $('.chat-export').hide();
            $('.chat-settings').hide();
            $('.chat-users').toggle();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Theres always `switch` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$('[class^=chat]').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("class").indexOf(element) > -1){  $(this).toggle();   }
   else { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

PS. The problem with my early code and antyrat's code is that when we hide everything, the toggle works unexpectedly.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3avLu2o/1/)

Comment: Many thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: @ErikEdgren glad to have helped! Cheers!

Comment: One problem though. `toggle()` seems not to be working with your solution :/ I can only show the element but not hide it again.

Comment: @ErikEdgren here you go

Comment: @ErikEdgren can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @ErikEdgren ah! That was sign problem. Replace < with >

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid this using this [`regex`](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) selector snippet for example:

```
$( 'div:regex(class, .chat-*)' ).hide();
$( '.chat-' + element ).toggle();
```

Comment: Very nice code, but I'm keep getting `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex` :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren sorry, I forget to mention that this requires to include this snippet: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/ . Look at Amit Joki answer as well, it's seems to be more native

Comment: Thanks. Amit Joki's answer worked very well, so I'll use his instead :) Many thanks for your answer. It was awesome!